# ServiceBusTrigger in an Azure priority queue

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I've setup an Azure ServiceBus topic with two subscriptions - one for high priority and one for low priority. I have SqlFilters on the subscriptions, and I've verified that messages are being correctly routed, but the priority isn't taken into account.

I'm using the `ServiceBusTrigger(topic, subscription)` attribute to receive messages, is there a way to prioritize queues using that attribute, or do I need to manually call my queues from the WebJob in the order I want them, and use a `NoAutomaticTrigger` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

> **Microsoft Azure does not provide a queuing mechanism that natively
>   support automatic prioritization** of messages through sorting.
>   However, it does provide Azure Service Bus topics and subscriptions,
>   which support a queuing mechanism that provides message filtering,
>   together with a wide range of flexible capabilities that make it ideal
>   for use in almost all priority queue implementations.

In topic priority is not like in queues. So it's filter. With low taged messages will go low filtered subscribtion in topic, high taged ones will go high filtered subscription. Filters just routes messages (Every subscription has different virtual queue).